# Expection Unhandled Error when implementing a LinkedList in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

Alright so I am attempting to implement a LinkedList data structure but when I try to loop through my list (printNodes and insert functions) I run into an error that says: "Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation. tmpNode was 0xCDCDCDCD." I feel like it has something to do with my pointers not behaving in the manner I think they should but I am not sure. Some assistance would be very much appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>;
using namespace std;
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;

    Node(int el) {data = el; } //constructor
    Node(int el, Node* ptr) { data = el; next = ptr; } //constructor
};

class LinkedList {

public:
    Node* head = NULL, * tail = NULL;
    void addToHead(int el) {
        head = new Node(el, head);
    }

    void insert(int el) {
        Node* newNode = new Node(el);
        if (head == nullptr) {
            head = newNode;
        }
        else {
            Node* tmpNode = head;
            while (tmpNode->next != nullptr) {
                tmpNode = tmpNode->next;
            }tmpNode->next = newNode;
        }
    }
    void printNodes() {
        Node* tmpNode = head;
        cout << tmpNode->data;
        while (tmpNode->next != nullptr) {
            std::cout << tmpNode->data;
            tmpNode = tmpNode->next;
        }

    }
};

int main() {
    LinkedList myList = LinkedList();
    myList.insert(10);
    myList.addToHead(20);
    myList.insert(10);
    myList.printNodes();
}
```

Comment: *I feel like it has something to do with my pointers not behaving in the manner I think they should but I am not sure.* -- So I take it that you didn't use the debugger?

Comment: Set `next` to `nullptr` in constructor: `Node(int el) {data = el; next = nullptr; }` at least.

Comment: You have a `tail` pointer -- use it, don't iterate to insert at end. You don't need an `insert`, just an `add` function, e.g. `void add (int el) { Node *newNode = new Node(el); if (head == nullptr) head = tail = newNode; else { tail->next = newNode; tail = newNode; }` Your `Node(int el) {data = el; }` constructor must initialize `next = nullptr;`, e.g. `Node(int el) {data = el; next = nullptr; }` as @Manuel shows above.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks I did that instead, but I still need to know how to iterate in order to do a linear search of the list.

Comment: Side note: you are dynamically allocating memory using new without a matching call to delete which is why you should use [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)!

Comment: @Pen_Fighter see [Singly Linked List of Integer](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A) the `prn`, `del_node` and `del_list` functions for 2-ways to iterate the list. (C, but implementation is the same) See [C++ Template Singly-Linked List w/Sort](https://pastebin.com/Sq1MPU15) for a full C++ Templated implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your iteration is correct, but there is a problem with your `printNodes` function. It dereference `tmpNode` without checking for `null`:

```
void printNodes() {
    Node* tmpNode = head;
    cout << tmpNode->data; // <-- here
    while (tmpNode->next != nullptr) {
        std::cout << tmpNode->data;
        tmpNode = tmpNode->next;
    }

}
```

I would change it to the following:

```
void printNodes() {
    Node* tmpNode = head;

    while (tmpNode != nullptr) {
        std::cout << tmpNode->data << ", ";
        tmpNode = tmpNode->next;
    }
}
```

Apart from that, as said in comments, if you set `next` member to `null` in `Node` constructor it should work fine.

To search, it is the same thing but checking for the data:

```
Node* findNode(int el) {
    Node* tmpNode = head;
    Node* ret = nullptr;

    while (tmpNode != nullptr) {
        if (tmpNode->data == el) {
            ret = tmpNode;
            break;
        }
        tmpNode = tmpNode->next;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And in `main`:

```
Node* n = myList.findNode(10);
if (n)
    std::cout << "N 10: " << n->data << "\n";

n = myList.findNode(30);
if (n)
    std::cout << "N 30: " << n->data << "\n";
else
    std::cout << "There is no N 30\n";
```

There are memory leak problems also, as specified by @RikusHoney in the comments.